# Inserting range to another sheet as rows multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy range from sample reference card into another sheet and insert this range as row on above existing ones, multiple times.

Right now I have code that is working for inserting this range once:

```
Sub Nova_karta_export()

    Sheets("nova_karta").Select
    Rows("3:42").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Export").Select
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

I was able to modify it to insert this range multiple times based on value in cell "V1" in export sheet. But running this version is quite heavy on computing.

```
Sub Nova_karta_export_X_krat()

    Dim numberoftimestorun As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
 
    numberoftimestorun = Sheets("Export").Range("V1").Value
    
    For i = 1 To numberoftimestorun
        
    Sheets("nova_karta").Select
    Rows("3:42").Select
    Selection.Copy
      
    Sheets("Export").Select
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    
    Next i
        
End Sub
```

If I insert range for example ten times is computes very slow. I need to add even 50+ ranges.

How can I speed up this process? Through variables?
And how to insert number of repeats through message window? I want that user can write number of repeat into window after running macro and not to be dependent on cell "V1"

Thanks for help.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar macro in a file, and it uses resize, something like so:

```
Dim numberoftimestorun As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim source As Range

numberoftimestorun = Sheets("Export").Range("V1").Value
set source = Sheets("nova_karta").Rows("3:42")
source.Copy
Sheets("Export").Rows("3:3").Resize(numberoftimestorun * source.Rows.Count).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

See if something like that would speed things up.
The code I borrowed from only used a single row as source, so I hope this works, untested.